# Compiling wsdlpull

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I am having troubles compiling wsdlpull on windows.

I have downloaded wsdlpull-1.24 at first and went to win32, then clicked on wsdlpull.dsw
I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, so I got asked to "convert to the current Visual C++ project format" which I did, and that gave me an error saying "Cannot load the project due to a corrupt project file", so I downloaded wsdl-1.23 and that worked.

My current issue right now is compiling the solution which does not completely succeed.
(I have right clicked the solution and clicked on clean, then rebuild)
Below is the log for building the solution.

I hope this helps.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: wsdlpull, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Soap.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>WSDLDebug.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>WsdlElement.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>WsdlInvoker.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>WSDLParser.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>ComplexType.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>ContentModel.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>Group.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>SchemaDebug.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>SchemaParser.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>SchemaValidator.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>SimpleType.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>TypeContainer.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>TypesTable.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>ConfigFile.cpp
1>w3c.cpp
1>XmlPullParser.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>XmlSerializer.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>XmlUtils.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>Message.cpp
1>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
1>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
1>Generating Code...
1>Creating library...
1>SchemaDebug.obj : warning LNK4221: no public symbols found; archive member will be inaccessible
1>WSDLDebug.obj : warning LNK4221: no public symbols found; archive member will be inaccessible
1>Creating browse information file...
1>Microsoft Browse Information Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.21022
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>wsdlpull - 0 error(s), 20 warning(s)
2>------ Build started: Project: wsdl, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: stocks, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: schema, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: print, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>schema : warning PRJ0009 : Build log could not be opened for writing.
4>Make sure that the file is not open by another process and is not write-protected.
6>------ Build started: Project: xml, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
6>xml : warning PRJ0009 : Build log could not be opened for writing.
6>Make sure that the file is not open by another process and is not write-protected.
2>Compiling...
3>Compiling...
4>Compiling...
5>Compiling...
6>Compiling...
4>schema.cpp
2>wsdl.cpp
3>stocks.cpp
5>print.cpp
6>roundtrip.cpp
4>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
4>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
5>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
5>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
6>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
6>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
2>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
2>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
3>c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(33) : warning C4005: 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT' : macro redefinition
3>        c:\development\wsdl pull\wsdlpull-1.23\src\xmlpull\wsdlpull_export.h(18) : see previous definition of 'WSDLPULL_EXPORT'
6>Compiling manifest to resources...
6>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
6>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
6>Linking...
6>roundtrip.obj : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '.\Debug\roundtrip.obj' or at 'c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
6>wsdlpull.lib(w3c.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '.\debug\wsdlpull.lib' or at 'c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
6>wsdlpull.lib(XmlPullParser.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '.\debug\wsdlpull.lib' or at 'c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
6>wsdlpull.lib(XmlSerializer.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '.\debug\wsdlpull.lib' or at 'c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
6>wsdlpull.lib(XmlUtils.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '.\debug\wsdlpull.lib' or at 'c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
6>Embedding manifest...
6>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
6>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
4>Compiling manifest to resources...
5>Compiling manifest to resources...
4>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
4>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
5>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
5>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
4>Linking...
5>Linking...
6>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
6>xml - 0 error(s), 7 warning(s)
4>schema.obj : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '.\schema.obj' or at 'c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>Compiling manifest to resources...
3>Compiling manifest to resources...
3>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
2>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
2>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
3>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2>Linking...
3>Linking...
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall XmlNode_t::~XmlNode_t(void)" (??1XmlNode_t@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::WsdlInvoker(void)" (??0WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE@XZ)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall XmlDoc_t::XmlDoc_t(class XmlNode_t const &)" (??0XmlDoc_t@@QAE@ABVXmlNode_t@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::WsdlInvoker(void)" (??0WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE@XZ)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall XmlNode_t::~XmlNode_t(void)" (??1XmlNode_t@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::WsdlInvoker(void)" (??0WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE@XZ)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall XmlNode_t::XmlNode_t(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int)" (??0XmlNode_t@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::WsdlInvoker(void)" (??0WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE@XZ)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class XmlNode_t & __thiscall XmlDoc_t::getRootNode(void)" (?getRootNode@XmlDoc_t@@QAEAAVXmlNode_t@@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::invoke(long,bool)" (?invoke@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE_NJ_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall XmlDoc_t::XmlDoc_t(class XmlNode_t const &)" (??0XmlDoc_t@@QAE@ABVXmlNode_t@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::WsdlInvoker(void)" (??0WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE@XZ)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlDoc_t::clear(void)" (?clear@XmlDoc_t@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::invoke(long,bool)" (?invoke@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE_NJ_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall XmlNode_t::XmlNode_t(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int)" (??0XmlNode_t@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::WsdlInvoker(void)" (??0WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE@XZ)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class XmlNode_t & __thiscall XmlDoc_t::getRootNode(void)" (?getRootNode@XmlDoc_t@@QAEAAVXmlNode_t@@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::invoke(long,bool)" (?invoke@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE_NJ_N@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall XmlDoc_t::xpath(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > &,unsigned int)" (?xpath@XmlDoc_t@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@3@I@Z) referenced in function "private: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::getAsStringFromXPath(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > *)" (?getAsStringFromXPath@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@AAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV34@IPAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@4@@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlDoc_t::clear(void)" (?clear@XmlDoc_t@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::invoke(long,bool)" (?invoke@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAE_NJ_N@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlNode_t::setText(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?setText@XmlNode_t@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class XmlNode_t & __thiscall XmlNode_t::addNode(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?addNode@XmlNode_t@@QAEAAV1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall XmlDoc_t::xpath(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > &,unsigned int)" (?xpath@XmlDoc_t@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@3@I@Z) referenced in function "private: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::getAsStringFromXPath(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > *)" (?getAsStringFromXPath@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@AAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV34@IPAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@4@@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlNode_t::addAttribute(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?addAttribute@XmlNode_t@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlNode_t::setText(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?setText@XmlNode_t@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlNode_t::setName(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?setName@XmlNode_t@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class XmlNode_t & __thiscall XmlNode_t::addNode(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?addNode@XmlNode_t@@QAEAAV1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall XmlNode_t::empty(void)const " (?empty@XmlNode_t@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlNode_t::addAttribute(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?addAttribute@XmlNode_t@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlNode_t::setName(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?setName@XmlNode_t@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlDoc_t::setProcessEnvAndBody(bool)" (?setProcessEnvAndBody@XmlDoc_t@@QAEX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::setProcessEnvAndBody(bool)" (?setProcessEnvAndBody@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEX_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall XmlNode_t::empty(void)const " (?empty@XmlNode_t@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::buildXmlTree(class XmlPullParser &,class XmlNode_t &,bool)" (?buildXmlTree@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEXAAVXmlPullParser@@AAVXmlNode_t@@_N@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall XmlDoc_t::getProcessEnvAndBody(void)const " (?getProcessEnvAndBody@XmlDoc_t@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::getProcessEnvAndBody(void)const " (?getProcessEnvAndBody@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QBE_NXZ)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlDoc_t::setProcessEnvAndBody(bool)" (?setProcessEnvAndBody@XmlDoc_t@@QAEX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::setProcessEnvAndBody(bool)" (?setProcessEnvAndBody@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEX_N@Z)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlDoc_t::setLazyRelativeMatch(bool)" (?setLazyRelativeMatch@XmlDoc_t@@QAEX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::setLazyRelativeMatch(bool)" (?setLazyRelativeMatch@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEX_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall XmlDoc_t::getProcessEnvAndBody(void)const " (?getProcessEnvAndBody@XmlDoc_t@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::getProcessEnvAndBody(void)const " (?getProcessEnvAndBody@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QBE_NXZ)
2>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall XmlDoc_t::getLazyRelativeMatch(void)const " (?getLazyRelativeMatch@XmlDoc_t@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::getLazyRelativeMatch(void)const " (?getLazyRelativeMatch@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QBE_NXZ)
2>./wsdl.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall XmlDoc_t::setLazyRelativeMatch(bool)" (?setLazyRelativeMatch@XmlDoc_t@@QAEX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::setLazyRelativeMatch(bool)" (?setLazyRelativeMatch@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QAEX_N@Z)
3>wsdlpull.lib(WsdlInvoker.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall XmlDoc_t::getLazyRelativeMatch(void)const " (?getLazyRelativeMatch@XmlDoc_t@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall WsdlPull::WsdlInvoker::getLazyRelativeMatch(void)const " (?getLazyRelativeMatch@WsdlInvoker@WsdlPull@@QBE_NXZ)
2>Creating browse information file...
3>.\stocks___Win32_Debug/stocks.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals
5>Embedding manifest...
4>Embedding manifest...
3>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\stocks___Win32_Debug\BuildLog.htm"
3>stocks - 16 error(s), 1 warning(s)
5>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
5>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
4>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
4>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
4>Performing Post-Build Event...
5>Performing Post-Build Event...
5>        1 file(s) copied.
4>        1 file(s) copied.
5>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
5>print - 0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
4>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\BuildLog.htm"
4>schema - 0 error(s), 3 warning(s)
2>Microsoft Browse Information Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.21022
2>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Development\Wsdl Pull\wsdlpull-1.23\win32\BuildLog.htm"
2>wsdl - 16 error(s), 1 warning(s)
========== Build: 4 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well eventually I just did the same thing with an earlier version 1.22. I couldn't build the whole solution, but I tried building each project individually by going through the order of dependency of each project, making sure that project has its dependents already compiled.
And apparently that worked.

Answer (score 2):

To fix it add the files XmlDoc.h and XmlDoc.cpp to wsdlpool project.